# How can I validate 'double' type within From Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm POSTing new product into my RESTful API and everything is being validated perfectly except doubles.
If I pass a double type for example '2.3' alert says that's incorrect and should be 2 or 3 instead.

```
const [isValidated, setIsValidated] = useState(false)

const handleSubmit = async event => {
    const form = event.currentTarget
    event.preventDefault()

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
        setIsValidated(true)
        await ProductsApiService.postProduct(product)

        props.onModalClose()
        props.onRefreshList()
        setIsValidated(false)
    }
}


<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} validated={isValidated}>
   <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="productPrice">
      <Form.Label>EUR</Form.Label>
         <Form.Control
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="number"
            name="eur"
            placeholder="Price EUR"
            required />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Row>
       <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
       Confirm
       </Button>
    </Form.Row>
</Form>
```

- and this is working properly with '2.0' for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern that Javascript validator API understands what type of number should deal with. so, for instance, the following pattern indicates the number input must start with a number and use either comma or a dot as a decimal character.

```
   <Form.Control
         onChange={handleChange}
         type="number"
         pattern="[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?" // the Regex for having 
         name="eur"
         placeholder="Price EUR"
         required />
```

you can search for "decimal validation regex" to see all possible types of creating a pattern